# Disabled button property on button not letting modal triggered?

Tags: bootstrap-4

As for now imagine that I have some fields in which it will accept some user input in an HTML form and it has a button **ORDER SAMPLE** having the pristine and invalid property. But the problem is that I want that when the user clicks on **ORDER SAMPLE** after filling all required fields the modal must appear(used for conforming the user that order has been placed) but when I click on **ORDER SAMPLE** button it does nothing. Please suggest me the correct way to solve this problem. Please Help!

Thanks in advance!

```
      <div class="text-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" [disabled]="ordrsampleFormGroup.pristine || ordrsampleFormGroup.invalid">
        Order Sample
      </button>
    </div>
      <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Modal title</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
<form>
  <input required>
  <input required>
  <input required>


  <div class="text-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg order_sampleBtn" [disabled]="ordrsampleFormGroup.pristine || ordrsampleFormGroup.invalid">
        Order Sample
      </button>
    </div>
      <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Modal title</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

</form>

<script>
//hides modal on load if clicked
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".order_sampleBtn").click(function(){
    $("#exampleModalCenter").modal({show: false});
  })
 });

$('.order_sampleBtn').on("click", function(){
  let valid = true;
  $('[required]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':invalid') || !$(this).val()) valid = false;
  })
  if (!valid) alert("error please fill all fields!");
  else $("#exampleModalCenter").modal({show: true});
})
</script>
```